# More Change Proposal Views

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

When viewing documentation change proposals, it can be difficult to pick out problems with formatting (and particularly difficult with code blocks). It would be helpful to have a "raw" view where reviewers can see the raw content of the proposal (possibly with highlighted changes), and possibly a "preview" view to see what the finalized documentation would look like once the edit is approved (in contrast to the side-by-side markdown editor).

Comment: The markdown view is not properly formatted and all the spaces which are there are being collapsed because that's the way HTML works. The second example is plain not formatted correctly. A code block needs a blank line above and below it, so it's not being interpreted as a code block because of the text directly above it.

Comment: @animuson Thanks. Am I missing possible ways of being able to determine that the formatting is not proper on my own? At the moment it seems unclear how to determine that.

Comment: You can look at the page source and see that the spaces are actually there.

Comment: @animuson Makes sense. Seems to be a bit of work to go through for reviewers, though. I guess I should separate the second part of my question (the feature request) into a new question, because having a "full view" and/or a "raw view" would definitely help.